# How do I force expiration of an ASP.Net session when a user leaves the site?

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

We have a scenario in which we like to detect when the user has left our site and immediately expire their .Net session. We're using Forms Authentication. We're not talking about a session timeout, which we already have. We would like to know when a user has browsed away from our site, either via a link, by typing in an address or following a bookmark. If they return to our site, even if right away, they will have to log back in (I understand this is not great usability - this is a security requirement we've been given by our client).

My initial instinct is that this is either not possible, or that any solutions will be extremely unreliable. The only solutions we've come up with are:

- Add a JavaScript onBlur event handler that tells the server to log out the session when the user leaves the site.
- Once the user has logged in, check the HTTP referrer to ensure that the user has navigated from within the site.
- Add AJAX polling back to the server to keep the session refreshed, possibly on a 10-second interval. When the call isn't received on time the session would end.

The onBlur seems like the easiest, but possibly least reliable method - I'm not sure if it would even work. There are also issues with the referrer method, as the user could type in an address within the site and not follow a link. The AJAX method seems like it would work, but it's complicated - I'm not even sure how to handle it on the back-end. I'm thinking there might also be scenarios in which that wouldn't always work.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone for a heartbeat type scenario like you describe above. Either Ajax Polling or an IFRAME. When the user closes the browser and a certain timeout elapses (10 seconds?), then you can log them out.

Another alternative would be to have the site run entirely on AJAX. Thus there is only one "URL" that a user can visit and all content is loaded dynamically. Of course you break all sorts of usability stuff this way, but at least you achieve your goal.

Comment: Have you done this with an ASP.Net app? How do you know on the backend when the polling hasn't made a call? In other words, how do you set up a listener for this if by definition a request isn't made?

Comment: We had an object that mapped session IDs to last received poll time. Whenever a page request was made we obtained the last last poll time. If too old or no entry, we signed them out. We periodically (every few minutes) cleared out old entries in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If the user closes their browser, or types in a different URL (including selecting a favourite) there is not much for you to detect.

For links on your site, you could create links that forward via your site (i.e. rather than linking to http://example.com/foo you link to http://mysite.com/forwarder?dest=http://example.com/foo).

Just be careful to only forward to sites you intend to, otherwise you can open up security issues with "universal forwarding" being used for phishing etc..

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely, positively need to tell the client that this is not possible.  They are having a basic misunderstanding of how the Web works.  Be diplomatic, obviously... hell, it's probably someone else's job... but it needs to be done.

Your suggestions, or a combination of them, may work in a simple proof-of-concept... but they will bring you nothing but support nightmares and will not work consistently enough.  Worse, you will undoubtably also create situations where users cannot use the application at all due to the security hacks misfiring on them.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always possible to dictate this to a client. We had a client bidding on a government contract. This was a requirement on the contract. The incumbent competitor already claimed (never verified) to be able to do it. So we really had no choice but to try and implement something.

Comment: Well, obviously the client wasn't happy with the incumbent, or you wouldn't have got the job.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has an onUnload event, which is triggered when the browser is told to leave the page. You can see this on StackOverflow when you try to press the back button or click a link while editing an answer.

You may use this event to trigger an auto-logoff for your site.

I am unsure, however, if this will handle cases wherein the browser is deliberately closed or the browser process externally terminated (I'm guessing it doesn't happen in the 2nd case).

Answer (score 0):

If all navigation within your site is done through .NET postbacks (no simple html links or javascript open statements), you can do automatic logoff and redirect to the login page if the page load is not a postback. This does not end the session on exit, but it looks like it because it enforces a login if manually navigating to your web app. To get this functionality for all pages, you can use a Master page that does this in the Page_Load.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
}
```